# Android gradle not importing from jar files

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Please help, i have included some jar files under libs directory in Android Studio and am compiling it like this in build.gradle :

```
fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

The sync with gradle files goes well with no errors but i can not import java classes inside the jars. So what's the problem ?.

This is not the first time i include a jar file like this and i had no problem before whether  with one file or not (fileTree).

I know i have options like importing the jar files as a library in project structure but i really want to know what's going on with this situation ??

I tried to clean the project but with no news !!

**My project structure and build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.support.android.designlibdemo"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
}
```

[image]

Comment: post your `build.gradle` and your directory structure. Make sure the ,jars are valid i.e., try opening them (since they are zip files).

Comment: Thank you man!!. As u said, they can not be even opened !!. I do not know why people share such unuseful jars !! :)

Comment: Yeah sometimes the proxy will stop them from being downloaded correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issues like this can be caused by corrupt .jars (possibly due to the action of a hostile proxy).

Check the .jars inside your `libs` directory. They are .zip files and can be opened with Windows Explorer or Finder. If they don't open, you will need to download them and try again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to **`compile`** the fileTree.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // ^^^
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat:24.2.0'
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your question is definitely missing the word "compile" in the Gradle block